# Problem retracting a Sharepoint 2010 Foundation solution

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-foundation, retraction

I am retracting a globally deployed solution via Central Administration.  Here is the info

```
Name: familycareprl.wsp 
Type: Core Solution 
Contains Web Application Resource: No 
Contains Global Assembly: Yes 
Contains Code Access Security Policy: No 
Deployment Server Type: Front-end Web server 
Deployment Status: Retracting(scheduled at 10/2/2011 7:04 PM ) 
Deployed To: Globally deployed.
```

What i don't understand is why the retraction is not immediate....it basically just sits there indicating that it is retracting.  I'm used to quick retraction via Visual Studio.  I have also run stsadm -o execadmsvcjobs to see if that would speed it up but it just sits there.  Couple notes.  It was deployed through powershell using

```
Add-SPSolution c:\familycareprl.wsp
Install-SPSolution -identity familycareprl.wsp -GACDeployment   (had to leave off the URL for it to work)
```

I initially forgot to deactivate the features before attempting the retract.  They are now deactivated.

Any help?

*EDIT*

Did a stsadm -o enumdeployments and got this

```
<Deployments Count="1">
   <Deployment JobId="daa0d839-af5a-401b-baa4-7bbda2d3f2b3">
      <Title>Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Solution Retraction for "familycare
prl.wsp"</Title>
      <Type>Retraction</Type>
      <State>Pending</State>Cannot open database "SharePoint_AdminContent_6f68eb
f3-27b1-4c25-a1e3-c83b5968b947" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'NA\cheever.m.1'.
```

What does this mean?  Why can i log into Central Admin and use Powershell (i am db_owner/db_securityadmin on the content database and config database).  Can anyone tell me what i need to ask my IT guy to do?

Comment: have you got it retracted?

Comment: No....see edit above

Comment: It seems you don't have access to the config Database.
Also make sure you right click log as an admin before you run the stsadm cmd.
Let me know how you go

Comment: I need db_owner and db_securityadmin on both the content and config database correct?  Is there anything i am missing in order to freely add/deploy/retract/delete a solution.  TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you just add your permissions to the database or have they been there a while?

Try cancelling the deployment ( `stsadm -o canceldeployment -id daa0d839-af5a-401b-baa4-7bbda2d3f2b3` ), then restart the timer service on all machines in the farm before trying again.

I've had issues in the past where updates to database permissions haven't quite worked until a service restart.

Comment: permissions was the problem